# How to set system-wide web browser

Tags: ubuntu, browser

I have several web browsers under Ubuntu 10.10, such as FIrefox, Google Chrome.
I installed Firefox first, and since I installed Google Chrome later, the default web browser for the system is changed to Google Chrome.

I can set up the default web browser to be Firefox for opening a saved html file by changing the property of html files.

But there are other applications which run the system-wide default web browser to connect to webpages on internet. Such as [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/).

I was wondering how to set the default web browser for the whole system? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is *Preferred Applications* in the *Preferences* menu.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Does it require to restart the OS to take effect?

Comment: It may need you to log out and in again, but I wouldn't have thought so.

Answer (score 1):

Preferred applications will work for GTK apps. Have a look also at `update-alternatives --display x-www-browser` and `update-alternatives --display gnome-www-browser`.